# how i install mysql in cent os 8 server?

Tags: mysql, centos

I did the following steps but got error

STEP 1)
 `rpm -Uvh https://repo.mysql.com/mysql80-community-release-el7-3.noarch.rpm`

STEP 2) 
`yum --enablerepo=mysql80-community install mysql-community-server`

** Problem: cannot install the best candidate for the job
  - nothing provides libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) needed by mysql-community-server-8.0.18-1.el7.x86_64
  - nothing provides libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit) needed by mysql-community-server-8.0.18-1.el7.x86_64
  - nothing provides libssl.so.10()(64bit) needed by mysql-community-server-8.0.18-1.el7.x86_64
  - nothing provides libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit) needed by mysql-community-server-8.0.18-1.el7.x86_64
  - nothing provides libaio.so.1()(64bit) needed by mysql-community-server-8.0.18-1.el7.x86_64
  - nothing provides libaio.so.1(LIBAIO_0.1)(64bit) needed by mysql-community-server-8.0.18-1.el7.x86_64
  - nothing provides libaio.so.1(LIBAIO_0.4)(64bit) needed by mysql-community-server-8.0.18-1.el7.x86_64
  - nothing provides net-tools needed by mysql-community-server-8.0.18-1.el7.x86_64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)**

ERROR AFTER

```
[root@centos-1cpu-1gb-fi-hel1 ~]# yum install libssl1.0.0 libssl-dev
Error: There are no enabled repos.
```

**MARIA DB ERROR**

> [root@centos-1cpu-1gb-fi-hel1 ~]# yum --disablerepo=AppStream install
>   MariaDB-server MariaDB-client No repository match: AppStream Last
>   metadata expiration check: 0:00:05 ago on Thu 14 Nov 2019 04:03:47 PM
>   UTC. Error:   Problem 1: cannot install the best candidate for the job
>     - nothing provides libstdc++.so.6()(64bit) needed by MariaDB-server-10.4.10-1.el8.x86_64
>     - nothing provides libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3)(64bit) needed by MariaDB-server-10.4.10-1.el8.x86_64
>     - nothing provides libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4)(64bit) needed by MariaDB-server-10.4.10-1.el8.x86_64
>     - nothing provides libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.8)(64bit) needed by MariaDB-server-10.4.10-1.el8.x86_64
>     - nothing provides libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.11)(64bit) needed by MariaDB-server-10.4.10-1.el8.x86_64
>     - nothing provides libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)(64bit) needed by MariaDB-server-10.4.10-1.el8.x86_64
>     - nothing provides libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.20)(64bit) needed by MariaDB-server-10.4.10-1.el8.x86_64
>     - nothing provides libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit) needed by MariaDB-server-10.4.10-1.el8.x86_64
>     - nothing provides libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.9)(64bit) needed by MariaDB-server-10.4.10-1.el8.x86_64
>     - nothing provides libaio.so.1()(64bit) needed by MariaDB-server-10.4.10-1.el8.x86_64
>     - nothing provides libaio.so.1(LIBAIO_0.1)(64bit) needed by MariaDB-server-10.4.10-1.el8.x86_64
>     - nothing provides libaio.so.1(LIBAIO_0.4)(64bit) needed by MariaDB-server-10.4.10-1.el8.x86_64
>     - nothing provides lsof needed by MariaDB-server-10.4.10-1.el8.x86_64
>     - nothing provides perl(DBI) needed by MariaDB-server-10.4.10-1.el8.x86_64  Problem 2: cannot install the
>   best candidate for the job
>     - nothing provides libstdc++.so.6()(64bit) needed by MariaDB-client-10.4.10-1.el8.x86_64
>     - nothing provides libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3)(64bit) needed by MariaDB-client-10.4.10-1.el8.x86_64
>     - nothing provides libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4)(64bit) needed by MariaDB-client-10.4.10-1.el8.x86_64
>     - nothing provides libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.8)(64bit) needed by MariaDB-client-10.4.10-1.el8.x86_64
>     - nothing provides libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.11)(64bit) needed by MariaDB-client-10.4.10-1.el8.x86_64
>     - nothing provides libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)(64bit) needed by MariaDB-client-10.4.10-1.el8.x86_64
>     - nothing provides libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.20)(64bit) needed by MariaDB-client-10.4.10-1.el8.x86_64
>     - nothing provides libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit) needed by MariaDB-client-10.4.10-1.el8.x86_64
>     - nothing provides libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.9)(64bit) needed by MariaDB-client-10.4.10-1.el8.x86_64
>     - nothing provides libaio.so.1()(64bit) needed by MariaDB-client-10.4.10-1.el8.x86_64
>     - nothing provides libaio.so.1(LIBAIO_0.1)(64bit) needed by MariaDB-client-10.4.10-1.el8.x86_64
>     - nothing provides libaio.so.1(LIBAIO_0.4)(64bit) needed by MariaDB-client-10.4.10-1.el8.x86_64 (try to add '--skip-broken' to
>   skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best
>   candidate packages)

Comment: why not MariaDB? yum install mariadb-server same but for opensource projects.

Comment: i try but got error too

Answer (score -1):

`libcrypto.so.10` needs to be installed first.

Lets make sure that you have your SSL installed and updated:

```
sudo apt-get update


sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0 libssl-dev
```

Change command to use YUM

Comment: this is not ubuntu server this is Centos but I will try.

Comment: yum install -y openssl-devel ??

Comment: already install 

`Package openssl-devel-1:1.1.1-8.el8.x86_64 is already installed.`